# Data structure in R grouping pairs of data

Tags: r, data-structures

I'm facing a problem to organize data for a process. The requirements are that we have N tugboats (a ship used to transport big ships) and N ships to be get by those tugboats. Each Ship require an especific number of tugboats, so we have something like this:

```
setClass("tugboat", slots=list(name = "character"))

tugboat1 <- new("tugboat", name = "tugboat 1")
tugboat2 <- new("tugboat", name = "tugboat 2")
tugboat3 <- new("tugboat", name = "tugboat 3")

setClass("ship", slots=list(name = "character", tugboats_required = "numeric"))

ship1 <- new("ship", name = "Titanic", tugboats_required = 1)
ship2 <- new("ship", name = "Black Pearl", tugboats_required = 1)
ship3 <- new("ship", name = "Interceptor", tugboats_required = 1)
```

what structure and logic i could use to mount all possible scenarios thinking that a tugboat can't engage in two ships at same time, example:

**SCENARIO 1**: ship1  + tugboat1, ship2 + tugboat2, ship3 + tugboat3

**SCENARIO 2**: ship1  + tugboat1, ship2 + tugboat3, ship3 + tugboat2

**SCENARIO 3**: ship1  + tugboat2, ship2 + tugboat1, ship3 + tugboat3

**SCENARIO 4**: ship1  + tugboat2, ship2 + tugboat3, ship3 + tugboat1

**SCENARIO 5**: ship1  + tugboat3, ship2 + tugboat1, ship3 + tugboat2

**SCENARIO 6**: ship1  + tugboat3, ship2 + tugboat1, ship3 + tugboat1

in example above, i'm consider just one tugboat for each ship (tugboats_required = 1), but if this number is 2 for example the scenario for that ship should have 2 tugboats. Example:

```
setClass("tugboat", slots=list(name = "character"))

tugboat1 <- new("tugboat", name = "tugboat 1")
tugboat2 <- new("tugboat", name = "tugboat 2")
tugboat3 <- new("tugboat", name = "tugboat 3")

setClass("ship", slots=list(name = "character", tugboats_required = "numeric"))

ship1 <- new("ship", name = "Titanic", tugboats_required = 1)
ship2 <- new("ship", name = "Black Pearl", tugboats_required = 2)
```

**SCENARIO 1**: ship1  + tugboat1, ship2 + tugboat2 + tugboat3

**SCENARIO 2**: ship1  + tugboat2, ship2 + tugboat1 + tugboat3

**SCENARIO 3**: ship1  + tugboat3, ship2 + tugboat1 + tugboat2

the problem is not tha math, the problem is to organize the data after objects declaration.

Comment: Is "two tugboats" your max, or does this problem scale? Also, you said `tugboats_required=2` but only list one for ship1, is this an acceptable gap considering you only have three tugs available?

Comment: this problem scale, but the value can't be bigger than 5 for each ship. "tugboats_required=2" is a property from ship2. Ship1 still have "tugboats_required = 1", it's not a gap (i'm not considering gaps at this moment)